# How to replace silicone seal in ceiling fan?

Tags: fans

I am having to replace damaged wire in a ceiling fan. To replace the wire, I had to remove what looks to be some sort of silicone seal in the neck of the fan housing, where the downrod connects to the housing. See pic. What is this stuff, and how do I replace it? If it is just expandable silicone foam, would just any expandable foam do or is there something specific for this sort of application?
[image]

Comment: This belongs on DIY.SE, I believe.

Comment: Would users in that community know about whether the silicon seal has to be specific for electrical wiring?

Comment: It doesn't look like a foam product to me.  It does look like plain silicone rubber sealant or caulk.

Comment: I propose that is just 'plain old white silicon RTV'.  It's used very often in electrical manufacturing, especially on PCB's to keep components from moving around.   I further propose that it's purpose here is to ensure the wires can not rub against the metal conduit and become frayed/short out.  It's a ceiling fan, so it has to be vibrating and moving around.   I would just cut it away to do your repair, then recreate the "glob" when done.  You can buy smaller tubes of RTV at the auto parts store (sure you know once you open the tube, it's generally gotta be used up right away)

Comment: Unlikely to be silicone, since most formulations *do not* foam. It could be any approved sealant; it's purpose is to reduce air infiltration, and to reduce motor vibration noise carried along the wires.